# Yeoman Angular Fullstack gulp buildcontrol:heroku : Failing

Tags: git, heroku, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

I was trying to deploy my sample angular-fullstack app to heroku so I did this `gulp buildcontrol:heroku`. But Im getting this error.

> [14:17:19] Requiring external module babel-register
>   [14:17:21] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/WiM/gulpfile.babel.js
>   [14:17:21] Starting 'buildcontrol:heroku'...
>   Running "buildcontrol:heroku" (buildcontrol) task
>
> fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.
>   Warning: fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.
>   Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

Im pretty sure I added the git url from heroku as a remote on my local git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue and it works for me after add  `the git url from heroku website` to **Gulpfile.js** under **buildcontrol.heroku.options.remote** object.

```js
 heroku: {
    options: {
       remote: 'https://git.heroku.com/the_name_of_your_app.git',
       branch: 'master'
    }
}
```